# Drawing a chemical molecule structure

Tags: chemistry

Being a mechanical engineer I never had the necessity to draw chemical formulas/molecule structures in LaTeX, but now I have to draw the structure of [Polyethylene glycol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene_glycol). So I was looking at examples of how to use [`chemfig`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Chemical_Graphics) and doing the chain was pretty basic, but I have no idea how to put the parentheses around the bit to be repeated *n* times. Could someone please help me out? Thanks!

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{H-[:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]O-[:30]H}
\end{document}
```

I got:

[image]

I need:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A starting point borrowed from the manual `chemfig` manual page number: 44.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
  \chemfig{H-[@{left,0.25}:30]O-[:-30]-[:30]-[@{right,0.25}:-30]O-[:30]H}
   \polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 20pt, depth = 10pt, indice = n]{left}{right}
\end{document}
```

you will get:

[image]

> **Disclaimer:** I am not sure about the technical accuracy. Because, I am not a chemist `:)`.

Comment: That should do it: I can tweak the position of the parentheses with the parameters I think. Thanks!

Comment: @Superuser27 you are welcome.